# Include two database results in one API request output using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

I am developing an API in Rails 3 and I got a user model and a message model.
I want the developer to be able to get all info about the user as well as the last message from the user. How can I do this? How can I "include" the messages into the user output?

How can this code be modified to suit my purpose?

```
def index

    @contacts = current_user.contacts

    @users = Array.new

    @messages = Array.new

    @contacts.each do |contact|

        user = User.find(contact.friend_id)

        @users << user

        message = Message.find_by_user_id(contact.friend_id)

        @messages << message

    end

    respond_to do |format|

        format.html { render :text => 'Use either JSON or XML' }
        format.json { render :json => @users }
        format.xml { render :xml => @users }

    end

end
```

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of your model, and include the last message as a method in your User model.  You can then use the :methods hash of the render method.

```
  format.json { render :json => @users , :methods => [:last_message]}
```

EDIT

Your user model should be something like:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  attr_accessor :name, :email #Include the fields you wish to show here

  def last_message
    self.messages.first
  end
end
```

And your controller:

```
def index

    @contacts = current_user.contacts

    respond_to do |format|

        format.html { render :text => 'Use either JSON or XML' }
        format.json { render :json => @contacts, :methods => :last_message }
        format.xml { render :xml => @contacts, :methods => :last_message }

    end

end
```

Comment: Sounds interesting! What should I write in the user model to get the last message? I am not sure how I should do that. Could you show me?

Comment: I know how to use what you propose and that is awesome. The only problem now is I want to get the messages per person. How can I send parameters to the user model method? Please help!

Comment: See my edits, let me know if there is anything unclear.  I would check how many SQL queries it is making, if it is required, there are some optimisations that could be made.

Comment: Getting clearer. Unfortunately I get errors: NameError (undefined local variable or method `this'.

Comment: Apologies, that should have been self.messages.first, if that doesn't work, try just messages.first.

Comment: Perfect! Now it works fine. Thank you so much! Is it possible to get more than messages? For example phones?

Comment: I am not 100% on your structure, but your JSON will respond with any variables set in your attr_accessor/attr_reader method.  You can also specify the fields in an include hash in the same way you have your methods hash, e.g.  :include => [:phone, :address]  Hope this helps.

Comment: Just one more note, the opposite is also true, so if you wish to remove any data from the output, you can use the :exclude option in the render method.  So if you want to exclude their email then you can do :exclude => :email

Comment: The output works perfectly. I have only one problem with it. I do not know how to access the messages in javascript. Please see this issue if you have some more time to spare :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689931/javascript-access-data-in-a-json-object-parsed-please-help