# Access data in a JSON object (parsed) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get the data "messages" from this JSON object. How can I do it in JavaScript?

To access for example the lastname I just use:

```
response[i].user.lastname
```

But how can I access the messages?

```
[
    {
        "user": {
            "last_message": {
                "message": {
                    "created_at": "2011-04-16T16:40:56Z",
                    "updated_at": "2011-04-16T16:40:56Z",
                    "to": null,
                    "id": 10,
                    "user_id": 28,
                    "message": "This is a message"
                }
            },
            "nickname": "thenicky",
            "id": 28,
            "lastname": "white",
            "firstname": "Sean",
            "bio": "A short bio",
            "email": "the@email.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
response[i].user.last_message.message.created_at
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwxj2/1/).

Comment: I get this error when I try it: Result of expression 'response[i].user.last_message' [undefined] is not an object.

Comment: @Jonathan Clark, works fine for me. Checkout the following live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwxj2/1/

Comment: Works fine now. It was a problem with cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`response[i].user.last_message.message`

Comment: What a fantastic answer. This deserves more recognition!

Answer (score 2):

### Some examples:

```
alert(response[0].user.last_message.message.id);    
alert(response[0].user.nickname);    
alert(response[0].user.lstname);
```

### and working code:

[JSFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MU8au/)